# Android biometrics auth with only fingerprint

Tags: android, authentication, biometrics

I'm trying to make biomertics authentication on my app.

is there any way to restrict user to use only fingerprint?

I saw fingerprintmanager deprecated and new biometrics plugin doesn't divide face and fingerprint.

but some apps are using fingerprint only.

what i wonder is Some of those app are using deprecated api? or there is way to restrict user?